# Неясно почему удален неплохой ответ

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок, аудит, удаление-ответов

Я чекал очередь проверок низкого качества и сломался на аудите этого вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/239757 . Там был примерно такой ответ 
: “посмотрите руководство на официальном сайте или скачайте программу". Я отметил что ответ нормальный, а мне написало что нет. Можете написать более подробно почему ответ плохой? Как по мне то ответ норм, и лучше его сделать уже нельзя.

Comment: Если там ссылка была, возможно как спам его снесли.

Comment: Ну хорошо, но почему я провалил из-за этого аудит? Система не может отличать типы тревог?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, система берет вопросы, снесенные как спам или оскорбление, и подсовывает как аудиты в очередь низкого качества. Проблема в том, что спам может выглядеть как нормальный ответ, поэтому и получаются странные аудиты.

Comment: _Удалено как спам или оскорбление 30 янв в 9:22
участником_

Comment: Это довольно банальный спам, продвигающий программу.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

К сожалению, это действительно спам:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Привести аргументы неплохо, [**почему**](https://www.mywot.com/scorecard/recoverytoolbox.com?utm_source=addon&utm_content=main_window) это спам. Спасибо.

Comment: Я не люблю WOT...

Comment: @СашаЧерных, согласно определению в диалоге отправки тревог, спам — это реклама продукта или услуги без раскрытия причастности автора ответа. В том диалоге, кстати, есть ссылка на статью «[Как не быть спамером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)», в которой, в свою очередь, есть следующий пункт: ***Лучше один раз увидеть, чем сто раз услышать!** Лучшим способом не получить имидж прожженого торгаша является демонстрация решения, а не простые утверждения, что решение проблемы существует*.

Comment: @СашаЧерных четыре ссылки на одинаковый домен видите? Реклама домена - согласны?  Приписку "пробный период"? Врядли компания такие услуги за так оказывает, верно? Кто-то раскручивает сайт таким образом - согласны?